# material design not working samsung S7

Tags: android-recyclerview, material-design, samsung-mobile

I just released my app using Material design patterns, am essentially using the out of box DrawerLayout/Nav and CardView/RecyclerView.
Here's the App if you want to try: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player  , Works on all my devices but users report on Samsung S7 not so much

Here's the definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/allotherelements"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainCardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main_card">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/device_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

Than insert Cards using:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton">
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New CheckBox"
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Volume"
                        android:id="@+id/volumeText"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/volumeslider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:max="15"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Adapter and and all are working fine on my Nexus 5, and OLD Asus tablet(on android 4.3).

My user reported an empty screen.   Has anyone heard of Samsung 7 having issues with RecyclerView or CardView